# Phase plane portrait center ellipse equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

If I have a system of differential equations, with coefficient matrix,
A=$\begin{bmatrix} 1&13\\-2&-1\end{bmatrix}$. The eigenvalues are $\lambda= \pm 5i$. The phase portrait is a center with a clockwise direction field. How would I go about determining the equation of one of the rotated ellipse orbits?

Answer (score 4):

Equation for the phase paths:
$$\frac {dx}{dy}=\frac {x+13y}{-2x-y}$$
$$({-2x-y}){dx}= ({x+13y})dy$$
$$-2x{dx}= ydx+xdy+13ydy$$
Note that $ydx+xdy=dxy$ :
$$-2x{dx}= dxy+13ydy$$
Integrate:
$$C=x^2+ xy+ \frac {13} 2 y^2$$
It's an ellipse.

Comment: Outstanding answer thanks!

Comment: yw @user707991....